# footer positioning

Tags: html, css, positioning, footer

I would like to position my footer at about 20 - 30px, or a percentage, from the bottom of the screen. From looking at the elements with * {outline: solid 1px} there is a rectangle along the bottom of the screen which must be either the html element or mark the bottom boundary of the body. I'm a little hazy on positioning elements and despite having played around with varius positioning options cannot get the footer where I want it. What is the best practice here? How should I position the footer?

Comment: Do you mean at the bottom of the content (below everything) or on the bottom of the screen? These are different types of positioning

Answer (score 0):

If you want it at the bottom (+30px) of the document

```
footer{
   position:absolute;
   bottom:30px;
}
```

if you want it at the bottom of the document, you would need javascript to calculate the window's height

and do something like (in jquery)

```
$('footer').css({'position':'fixed','top':$(window).height()-$('footer').height()});
```

or with only CSS you can also do:

```
.footer{
    position:fixed;
    height:2%;
    top:98%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any of your code, it's hard to imagine why things aren't working for you. But my first guess is that you haven't styled the `body` element properly. By default, many modern browsers apply some sort of padding or margin to the body. As such, you should use the following rule to reset it:

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

This will reset the defaults, allowing you to proceed as you like. You could also use the `position: fixed` CSS rule for the element you want fixed to the bottom of the screen. Example:

```
#footer { position: fixed; bottom: 0; height: 30px; }
```